# PostgreSQL to Oracle migration through drag and drop in SQuirreL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration, squirrel-sql

I need to convert the structure of PostgreSQL databases to Oracle.

I use [SQuirreL SQL Client 3.3.0](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) with MDI interface and I opened two sessions: one for PostgreSQL, another for Oracle. MDI interface allows to move objects between schemas (drag and drop).

[image]

But when I move objects between schemes, I get an exception:

> [AWT-EventQueue-1]  ERROR
>   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.dnd.FileEditorDropTargetListener
>   -  handleUriListFlavor: no support for text/uri-list data flavor

What does this error mean and how can I use SQuirreL SQL Client for migration of table structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! **It works**. But only in the version of SQuirreL SQL Client **2.5**.

[image]

Ie by using simple drag and drop, you can make database migration.